Working with virtual microphone in Nextjs - can I real-time transcribe what I hear?
I am currently working on a Nextjs application that real-time transcribes the audio data from the system audio.
enter image description here
As a mac user, I use BlackHole for loopback. And I have setup all the essentials according to the BlackHole tutorial.
For my frontend setup, I am using the native WebRTC to connect the input source to BlackHole, which captures the system audio output. However, when I send the audio data to Deepgram live streaming API, there's no result returned.
enter image description here
I have tested the Deepgram API, it works well with my Built-in microphone. And there's also data going through the input source. I am not sure which part of code failed to be executed.
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
I am referencing https://github.com/deepgram-starters/nextjs-live-transcription/tree/main for the initial setup. Can you please help?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
